# Vector line output from solid models

Tags: rendering

I've been using 3Ds Max with the Illustrate! plug-in to get vector graphics for Illustrator. I recently updated 3Ds max to the 2023 version, and the plug-in no longer works. I would like to switch to Blender. Is there a way to do this in Blender? Or, is a plug-in for Blender available? I'm still learning and I don't even know where to begin. If the rendered result is of good quality, it doesn't need to be vector output, but it's preferred. The first image shown is a screen grab of the model. And the second one is the Illustrate! output.
Any help is appreciated.

Steve
[image: This is a typical model I start with]

[image: This is what I end up with]

Comment: Hello ! You should look into the Line Art modifier or the freestyle rendering technique (Line Art is more state of the art, freestyle is more thoroughly documented)

Comment: What Gorgious said, plus I think one or both will export to vector.